# Converting matlab code, into c

Tags: c, matlab

i have a matlab function that reads a big matrix and calculates the Singular Value Decomposition SVD. I however need to run that on a linux system without needing to install matlab on every new system, so id like to have it converted into c source code. The code is realy simple:

```
function singular(m)
load c:\som\matlab.txt
[U,S,V]=svd(matlab);
m = str2num(m);
U1=U(:,1:floor(sqrt(m)));
V1=V';
Vt=V1(1:floor(sqrt(m)),:);
S1=S(1:floor(sqrt(m)),1:floor(sqrt(m)));
matlab1=U1*S1*Vt;
matlab2=abs(matlab1);
save c:\som\matlab1.txt matlab1 -ascii
save c:\som\matlab2.txt matlab2 -ascii
```

Comment: Does it have to be `c`? You might find it easier to convert to Python, numpy has matlab like syntax and comes with a lot on Linuxes. Unless you already know C in which case you should post you attempt at porting it yourself.

Comment: @Dan The matrixes i will be processing will be enormous, and the completion times will have to be within 10 sec, so i need it in c.

Comment: You'll need a good maths library like http://www.netlib.org/clapack/ to get `svd`

Comment: *The code is really simple* ... `svd(matlab)`.  Yep, that's really simple.  Whatever you do, don't write your own svd routine, use a library such as Lapack.

Comment: You can try use it as MEX file, then you don't need to install Matlab on the target machine.

Comment: Easy way is to compile your program if you have the matlab compiler. Else to use python under linux, that can be really easy. And like other said, if you use C, you need a library for that.

Comment: @Adiel: A MEX file requires MATLAB, but as Alexandre suggests, the MATLAB compiler can generate standalone executables that only need the runtime libraries.  For third party SVD I would suggest MKL if you have a license, otherwise look at Eigen or Armadillo (assuming C++ is no problem).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Matlab coder](https://www.mathworks.es/products/matlab-coder/), but I advise you to make it manually, because some functions are not convertible, and the performance is not much better that mading it manually.

To make svd manually: [SVD](http://www.public.iastate.edu/~dicook/JSS/paper/code/svd.c)

Comment: The performance would be MUCH, MUCH better than making it manually!  Use a proper linear algebra library, not your own code or even some Numerical Recipes-inspired functon.

Comment: Well, you´re right in the most cases, but may be there is no library for some too-specific functions. I am also willing to reuse libraries instead of making it manually :)

Comment: Fair enough, but it has what's needed in this case: http://www.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ug/functions-supported-for-code-generation--alphabetical-list.html   On the other hand, the Compiler supports every last MATLAB function via the royalty-free MCR (runtime).