# Can I call Python from Matlab and generate C code for it?

Tags: matlab, matlab-compiler

Let's consider this simple Matlab script:

```
p=py.list([1,2,3])
disp(py.len(p))
```

this prints `3` .

Is it possible to generate C code for this script?

Comment: Might be helpful to you http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/287941/How-to-convert-matlab-code-to-C

Comment: Thanks Dave, but unfortunately those links do not answer the question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19156580/converting-matlab-code-into-c

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845292/a-tool-to-convert-matlab-code-to-python

Comment: What do you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say "generate C code from this script", I assume you're asking whether it's possible to use MathWorks code generation products (e.g. MATLAB Coder) to convert this script to C code.

If so then no - MATLAB Coder converts MATLAB code to C, and it only converts a subset of the MATLAB language to C. Most of the MATLAB language is covered, but there are some notable exceptions, and calls out to Python are one of them. I'm not sure whether you're hoping that you might be able to convert the Python itself to C code, or whether you're just hoping to generate C code that would call out to Python - but neither are possible.

Of course, you could

1. (manually) convert the Python code to MATLAB, and then use MATLAB Coder to generate C code from the MATLAB

or

2. (manually) convert the Python code to C code, and have MATLAB call the C code.

Comment: Or 3. Use Cython to convert the Python code to C code, and have MATLAB call the C code.

Comment: Sam : many thanks for the useful answer! Exactly this was my question.

Comment: I like the 3rd approach. Can Cython convert any Python code to C ?

Comment: No, it is really a way of writing C/Python interfaces using a Python-like syntax.  But for most fairly "ordinary" Python (including stuff using `numpy`) you can write Python code and convert it to C code.